# Event that automatically goes over all links

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I'm writing a jQuery script that adds tooltips to specific links on my web application. The website is constantly adding new links. What I'm trying to do is make it so that, the script will automatically go over all the links on the page and over new ones.

Furthermore, the script also modifies the link itself by changing its colour and prefixing an image before it. This is why I need to keep looking for new links automatically.

What kind of events would I have to hook into to make this happen?

Comment: Can you tell the example - when yout link change color?

Comment: It's some server side information. Depending on what the link targets, a different kind of tool tip is shown.

Comment: I ask you when it have to be happend? When you mouse cursor near the link? Or when you clicked?

Comment: i added fiddle, check? @JesseBrands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want attach event on all links, event if they're dynamically added, you have to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
  // ..some code
});
```

You can change `'click'` to another different event like `'hover'` and etc.

Try this fiddle, is it what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/btr3dLcx/3/

And btw - better use `data` attribute like `data-color-change-to='red'`

Comment: Thanks, that solves 50% of the problem. I edited the question, could you take another look?

Comment: @JesseBrands yeah, and ans to my question, and i gave you the code, mb with fiddle

Comment: That's not what I need, no. I need the link always to be that colour. However, I found a solution myself. I will accept your answer.

Comment: so, u can just remove second event 'mouseleave' in my fiddle, and thats the ans, glad, that u find solution.